# How can i left join two columns in pandas keeping both the join columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using:

```
 df1.merge(df2, on = 'id' , how='left' ,suffixes= ('_df1','_df2'))
```

The join column however merges into one. i.e. only one id column shows but i would like both the id columns to show so i can see which ids were actually missing/in common between the two. Unfortunately for my data you can have an ID but the contents of the right table (df2) may be different so i cannot simply filter on where null for the df2 table.

i.e df2 may look like the below so if i left join and filter where cost for example or name is null it is not actually missing in df2 it just doesn't have a value so i really need both ids from both dfs when joining

```
id | cost | gross | name | 
123| null | null  | null
```

How can i show both cols when i join?

Comment: You may want to use `.join()` instead of `.merge()`.

Answer (score 0):

one way about it is to use indicator parameter

```
df1.merge(df2, on = 'id' , how='left' ,suffixes= ('_df1','_df2'), indicator=True)
```

for my dummy test data it shows like this

```
ID  idx     _merge
0   87  1   left_only
1   87  2   left_only
2   87  3   left_only
3   87  4   both
4   87  5   both
```

```
df1.merge(df2, on = 'id' , how='left' ,suffixes= ('_df1','_df2'), indicator='Found in')
```

```
ID  idx     Found in
0   87  1   left_only
1   87  2   left_only
2   87  3   left_only
3   87  4   both
4   87  5   both
```

Alternately, temporarily rename the column you're joining on in the merge

```
df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'id':'id2'}), left_on = 'id', right_on='id2 , how='left' ,suffixes= ('_df1','_df2')
```

again, on my dummy test DF

```
    ID  idx     ID2
0   87    1     NaN
1   87    2     NaN
2   87    3     NaN
3   87    4     87.0
```